# Python dictionary popitem infinite loop potential

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible for an algorithm of the form:

```
while dict:
  k, v = dict.popitem()
  ... #arbitrary program statements
  ...
  if ...: #reinsert key in some cases
    dict[k] = v
```

To loop infinitely? In other words does the implementation of dictionaries/popitem guarantee that if I pop an item, decide that it should be reinserted, and the re-execute the loop, then that same item will be popped again?

Comment: It depends on the implementation.

Comment: be careful that : If the dictionary is empty, calling popitem() raises a KeyError.

Comment: It is if you use `collections.OrderedDict` and `d.popitem(last=True)`. Otherwise, the item that `popitem()` returns is not guaranteed to be the one you last inserted.

Comment: `popitem()` removes the 'first' key in the dictionary order. Popping an item, then inserting it back in again does *not* guarantee the same slot will be used again.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this construct? Do you only want to consider any key/value pair once? Or do you want to cycle over the dict entries until eventually all are gone?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is possible. But note that this depends on the precise implementation *and* python version.

`dict.popitem()` will pop the *first* key-value pair in the dictionary hash table. Because of hash collisions, reinserting the same key does not guarantee that it'll end up in the same slot again.

This is easily demonstrated in CPython 2.7, using integer keys:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 7: 7}
>>> d.popitem()
(1, 1)
>>> d[1] = 1
>>> d.popitem()
(7, 7)
```

In CPython (for versions before 3.3), a small dictionary starts with just a few slots in the hash table (as a dictionary grows more space is created dynamically), and `1` and `7` happen to hash to the same slot.

The first time I popped an item out of the dictionary there, `1` was returned, but reinserting `1` now leaves `7` as the first key and it is returned instead.

(Python 3.3 introduced a randomized hash seed, making hash collisions unpredictable).

But of course, it is perfectly possible to end up with a key that'll be inserted and removed over and over again, if only because it is the last key in the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {1: 1}
>>> d.popitem()
(1, 1)
>>> d[1] = 1
>>> d.popitem()
(1, 1)
```

You just cannot easily *predict* this will happen.

Note that regardless of what key is popped out next, if you keep re-inserting keys into the dictionary, your dataset doesn't shrink and you end up with an infinite loop *anyway*. It doesn't matter if that loop processes *one* key each time or a repeating series of keys.

Perhaps you were looking for a queue instead? There is a helpful and efficient [`collections.deque()` double-ended queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) implementation available:

```
from collections import deque

to_process = deque(d.items())  # initialize with key-values
while to_process:
    k, v = to_process.popleft()

    # do work with item

    if somecondition:
        to_process.append((k, v))
```

You still can end up with an infinite loop (if your `if` statement always re-inserts the same key-value pair, for example), but you at least you can guarantee that you'll first looked at *all* key-value pairs before you start looping.

Comment: Okay, but is it guaranteed that it /won't/ loop infinitely?

Comment: @ZachHalle: no, you *can* end up with the same item.

Comment: @ZachHalle: There, clarified further to show that the last key *would* end up looping indefinitely.

Comment: @ZachHalle, think about it:  in each iteration, you pop one key from the dict, and *possibly* add one key to the dict.  So across an iteration, the total number of items in the dict either remains the same or goes down by 1.  If "remains the same" is true on every iteration, then *of course* it's an infinite loop.  But *whether* "remains the same" is true on every iteration depends entirely on what your "if" test does - and you haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Does hash randomization apply to `int`?  (quick unscientific tests say "No").  I was under the impression that it only applied to `str` (and maybe `bytes`)

Comment: @mgilson: ah, of course; seeding only applies to a subset of types (`str`, `bytes` and `datetime`). It says so [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @mgilson, no hash randomization applies only to `str`, `bytes` and `datetime` objects.  It wasn't a really good idea even then ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: of course, that does mean that as soon as you insert one of those into a dict, from there on out any other type keys are affected as well as they'll now randomly collide with the seeded keys.

Comment: @mgilson: If you time your attack *just so*, a cache or other structure using `datetime` keys in a server could be made to massively collide..

Comment: Best I know, no such hashing DOS attack has ever been seen in the wild, only demonstrated by programs with full access to run any Python code they like.  But we're straying far from the OP's question here ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters: The Plone security team was given a fully working demo exploit that'd bring a Zope server to its knees. It was certainly feasible to use that attack on production servers.

Comment: Heh - like bringing Zope to its knees is an accomplishment?  LOL ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters: I lost count of the number of ways you could do use to make Zope keel over. But the exploit was translatable to other Python web servers too, unless drastic limits were set on the acceptable POST size.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sure - but if you ask the security wonks who originally publicized this exploit, Python's hash randomization is an inadequate response.  Yawn ;-)

Comment: Personally, I felt that that report was rather overhyped. But most security reporters are in it for the publicity, really.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the behavior is undefined.  Instead, iterate over copy.deepcopy(dict_).

EG:

```
for key, value in copy.deepcopy(dict_).items():
    do_something_with_dict(dict_)

# do_something_with_dict can change keys or values however it wants, without worrying
# that the for loop will get messed up
```

Comment: I would think that doing something like `dictInstance.copy().copy()` would be the same thing as one `copy` though...

Comment: Does someone not understand how this helps?  Why the downvotes?  It's a little pesky getting downvotes without any comment as to why.

Comment: SimonT: where are you getting .copy.copy?  There's no .copy.copy here.

Comment: While this may be appropriate for the OP's use case, the OP's code does not invoke undefined behavior. Repeated `popitem` calls may be freely mixed with modifications to the dict. For some algorithms, doing so may be superior to iteration with a `for` loop.